# Query for retrieve data with user fk Django 1.11

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to retrieve data from user. I have my model like this:

```
from django.db import models
```

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

## Create your models here.

```
class informacionFacturacion(models.Model):
    usuario = models.ForeignKey(User)
    apellidos = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="editar")
    nombres = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="editar")
    telefono = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="editar")
    email = models.EmailField(default="editar", null=False)
    direccion_1 = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="editar")
    direccion_2 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    provincia = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="editar")
    ciudad = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="editar")
    codigoPostal = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="editar")
    empresa = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="editar")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.usuario
```

My form for update user information:

```
from .models import informacionFacturacion

class informacionFacturacionForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = informacionFacturacion
        fields = [
            "usuario",
            "apellidos",
            "nombres",
            "telefono",
            "email",
            "direccion_1",
            "direccion_2",
            "provincia",
            "ciudad",
            "codigoPostal",
            "empresa",
        ]
```

And in my view I have my query like this

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .models import informacionFacturacion
from .forms import informacionFacturacionForm
@login_required
def datosPersonales(request):
    form = informacionFacturacionForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()
    query = informacionFacturacion.objects.filter(usuario=request.user)
    context = {
        "titulo": "Datos personales | Cadenas Giordanino S.R.L" + request.user.username,
        "body_class": "class= sidebar_main_open sidebar_main_swipe",
        "form": form,
        "infoFacturacion": query,
    }
    template = "micuenta/datosPersonales.html"
    return render(request, template, context)
```

And this QuerySet is empty.

I need to retrieve this data in the user profile

**UPDATE: ** Full code on post.

**UPDATE 2: ** For displaying the user data on profile, im using a "For loop". This data, is retrieved in "value=" attr of html inputs. If the user has no data, the form dosnt show.

**This is the way I wanna show the data. I populated this form from the same form u see here.**
[image: This is the way I wanna show the data. I populated this form from the same form u see here.]

**Here's when i enter for first time to my profile with no data**
[image: Here's when i enter for first time to my profile with no data]

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The field in your model is called `user` and not `user_id`. So: `.filter(user=request.user)`

Comment: Don't work. Queryset still  [ ] :/

Comment: I'll update the question with my full code soon as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that `request.user` is the user you've linked your `anotherModel` to? If you aren't currently logged in then `request.user` will be an instance of `AnonymousUser`. See more in the Documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.user

You can use the Django Shell for testing your models:

```
$ python manage.py shell
```

Then make some models:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from models import AnotherModel

# Grab a User
user = User.objects.first()

# Create a new anotherModel, linking the user
my_model = AnotherModel(
    user=user,
    address="whatever"
)
my_model.save()

my_model.user == user
>>> True
```

Comment: If you're 100% that your queryset is empty, then the only explanation left is that you're not actually saving your `informacionFacturacion` model with a reference to a user.

Comment: The queryset is now working well. My problem now is the imgs  I've posted.  Do I need to create a new question for this? Or can I be helped here

Comment: @FedericoRibero you should post another question :)

Comment: So this problem was solved. Thanks for your support.